# Trick webpage that tab is active with tabs.executeScript

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to make an addon which harvest some data from inactive tab.
The problem is this site somehow detects it's inactive and load data only if user looking at it (tab is active). Of course I can activate it for a sec, reactivate previous tab and collect data after it loads but this jumping between tabs is ridiculous and I'm searching for a way to convince this webpage to think I'm looking at it so it starts loading data I want.

Comment: Does https://greasyfork.org/scripts/7871-focus-true work for you?